# Handle long response time in fetch

Tags: reactjs

I am using fetch to get the data from the API but since the API is taking long time to fetch the data causing unable to fetch error.So how to handle this situation or how can i increase the response time??

Comment: You are sure it has to do with the time it takes for the fetch and not the routes?

Comment: Yes it is only related to the time because in case of less records no error is coming.